# How do I remove kitchen sink sprayer hose?

Tags: hose, kitchen-sink

The sprayer is cracked and leaks like crazy. The replacement I bought does not fit on the existing hose. I thought this would be a real easy to remove the existing hose and put a new hose and sprayer in. I think it's one of those quick-disconnect types, but I can't figure out how to disconnect the sprayer from under the sink.  Please see the pictures below.  Any ideas would be helpful.

[image]
[image]

*Edit: For reference, I have recently learned that this assembly is a Pfister Marielle faucet.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a "push-to-connect" fitting. You disconnect by pushing the tube, pushing the gray ring, then (while still pushing the gray ring) pulling the tube:

[image]

Comment: So I finally got around to replacing the entire faucet (it's a long story) and your description was tremendously valuable during the removal of everything. Thanks again, I really appreciate it!